# Material-UI v5 Menu Component styles are not being applied

Tags: material-ui, styles

I am having trouble styling the Menu component in Material-UI v5.

I have this UI:

[image: Current UI]

```
    <Menu
      defaultValue={undefined}
      id="simple-menu"
      open={openMenu}
      onClose={onCloseHandler}
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      MenuListProps={{ onMouseLeave: onCloseHandler }}
      elevation={0}
      sx={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
    >
```

When I use this code all the UI gets blue:

[image: All blue UI]

After that I try to apply global style overrides to the paper of the menu, but nothing happened. The styles did not change:

```
    components: {
        MuiMenu: {
          styleOverrides: {
            paper: {
              backgroundColor: arcBlue,
              color: arcBlue,
              borderRadius: "0px",
            },
          },
        }
    }
```

Please some help here

Answer (score 1):

Passing `sx` directly on the `Menu` component applies the styles to the component's root (which is what's causing your style modifications to apply to the overlay blanket).

In your case, since you're attempting to only style the MUI list portion of the menu, you want to pass the `sx` prop directly to the *underlying* list component, using the `MenuListProps` prop.  For example:

```
<Menu
  id="basic-menu"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  MenuListProps={{
    sx: { backgroundColor: "blue" }
  }}
>
```

Which produces:

[image: example image]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-glitter-cj83rc?file=/demo.tsx:758-951

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it working with this code in the sx prop:

{
      [`& .${paperClasses.root}`]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
    },

But I think your solution is more elegant, thanks

Comment: using the MenuListProps attribute on the Menu component worked for me. I did run into some other weird little things inside that nested sx prop like: 
- not being able to access the theme object
- setting OnMousLeave causes the following error "react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Header`) while rendering a different component (`MuiMenuList`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `MuiMenuList,`"

But I was able to take care fo the background color issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same course on Udemy, and I found another way to target the nested component you're styling using the parent Menu components sx-prop and not the nested sx-prop of the MenuListProp attribute like in the first answer.

I did use the first answer before figuring this one out:

- The example from the docs can be found in the section titled "Overriding nested component styles"
  link: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#the-sx-prop

Here is how it looks in my code:
[image]

And here is what the styled paper looks like in the browser:
[image]